# How do I convert N displayed arrays (each array visually similar to a PNG) into an mp4 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, mp4, display

I'm creating a code that outputs arrays that change over time per iteration. The details don't matter too much; I just need a way to get the arrays that are outputted, save them, and then stitch them into an mp4.

Here's the basic idea:

```
def display(A):
    %matplotlib qt 
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [6, 6/maxX*splitmarker] #maxX and splitmarker are the dimensions of the array
    plt.imshow(A, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = 'Blues');
    
    plt.axis('off'); 
    plt.show()
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.2)
```

to actually display the array A. Then, for a previously defined number of iterations,

```
for i in iterations:
    #the array is changed
    display(A)
```

This displays a new array A for every i. I'm trying to find a way to get all of those displays and stitch them together in a single mp4 file (so you can see how A progresses in time). There are 2 main obstacles I'm running into:

1: I don't know how to save the arrays as individual PNGs.

2: Even if I did know how to do that, I don't know how to convert the PNGs into an mp4 using Python.

I've already tried using FFMpegWriter and OpenCV3, but I can't figure out how to actually implement them into my code. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this [example FFMpegWriter function](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/animation/moviewriter.html), but it doesn't really work (since I can't define a DPI that works for the array).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite follow - what should the mp4 look like, and how would the video correspond to the content of your arrays? Also, you understand that video formats like mp4 do lossy compression, yes?

Comment: Well, display(A) displays an array. Each array visually looks something like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1uYP.png), format-wise. The mp4 would take each displayed array and stitch them together. It would basically look like a bunch of PNGs, one after the other, at a rate of around 15 fps. I do know that mp4s have lossy compression, but that's a limitation I'm stuck with.